# Android image share intent - how can I exclude a particular handler from the list?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

In my Android App I have an image loaded from Instragram API and I share it via the generic Share Intent like this:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

By default it gives a list of all installed apps that handle this intent, including Instagram which is the original source from where the image is coming from. How can I filter this list to exclude only the Instagram App from handling the intent while leaving all the rest?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I filter this list to exclude only the Instagram App from handling the intent while leaving all the rest?

You can't, except by creating your own chooser activity, using `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager` and somehow filtering out Instagram. Doing that will be unreliable, simply because there are multiple possible Instagram clients, whose package names are not conclusively knowable in advance.

I'd just leave Instagram there as an option.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to filter the shareintent for instagram.

```
List<Intent> targets = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent template = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
template.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> candidates = this.getPackageManager().
queryIntentActivities(template, 0);

// remove all intent except instagram in share intent
for (ResolveInfo candidate : candidates) {
    String packageName = candidate.activityInfo.packageName;
    if (packageName.contains("instagram")) {
       Intent target = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       target.setType("text/plain");
       target.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share"));
       target.setPackage(packageName);
       targets.add(target);
    }
}
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(targets.remove(0), translate("Share Via"));
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targets.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivity(chooser);
```